# New column values based on another column date

Tags: vba, excel

I need some guidance for this. I have a set of data. In column A there are dates from 01/01/2015 to 12/31/2015 filled down the row. What I am trying to achieve is to create a new column and fill it with values based on the date.

For example if column A row 1 has date 01/16/2015, the new column will have the value "Jan-15" . Basically if the date falls between 01/16/2015 and 02/15/2015, it will have the value "Jan-15". If it falls between 02/16/2015 and 03/15/2015, it will have the value "Feb-15".

This is what I have right now. The problem is; there is no value input into the new column. Just a blank column with a header.

```
Sub Month() 
    Dim Found As Range 
    Dim LR As Long 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Dim cell As Range 
    Dim a As Variant, v As Variant, num 
    Set ws = Sheets("PAYABLES - OUTFLOWS") 
    Set Found = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Due Date", _ 
    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 
    If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 
    a = [{"#01/18/2015", Jan; "#01/19/2015", Jan; "#01/20/2015", Jan}] 
    LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row 
    Found.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Insert 
    ws.Cells(1, Found.Column + 2).Value = "Month" 


    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Cells(LR, 3)) 

        v = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, a, 2, False) 
        cell.EntireRow.Cells(Found.Column + 2).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "", v) 
    Next cell 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your dates are in `A1:A3` this might work for you:

```
Sub GetMonth()
    Dim dates As Range, dt As Range

    Set dates = Range("A1:A3")

    For Each dt In dates

        If VBA.DatePart("d", dt) < 16 Then
            dt.Offset(0, 1) = dt
        Else
            dt.Offset(0, 1) = VBA.DateAdd("m", 1, dt)
        End If

        dt.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"

    Next dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much. It works like a charm. However, what if i want it to be as "Feb-15" instead of 02/15/2015?

Comment: Either format the entire column using `Format Cells > Custom > mmm-yy` or use the `Format` function in the VBA.